# Is it possible to use query parameters on the Django Admin Site

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant, query-string

I work with multi-tenancy and am passing the `schema name` through a query parameter. My `middleware` takes care of the parameter and sets the correct schema. It works very well on my API requests (direct **posts** and **gets**), but now I need to access the admin page for each of my schemas by specifying the schema name on a URL query parameter.

Here's the problem:

When I access

`http://localhost:8000/admin/?schema_name=myschema`

my `middleware` catches the parameter, but the admin site redirects me to a login page with this URL:

`http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/%3Fschema_name%3Dmyschema`

After this redirection it seems that it goes through my `middleware` again, this time without the `?schema_name=myschema` parameter, causing my `middleware` to set the schema to public everytime Django redirects a URL.

Is there a way to make the Django Admin site aware of this parameter even when some redirection changes the URL? (or maybe even a suggestion of a different approach I could use to make the Admin Site tenant aware).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Was just working on the same problem.

Problem is that django admin catches any uknown(unregistered via some filter on admin view) query params and if any found raises exception which redirects

Solution is to call something like that inside middleware:

```
def extract_client_id_from_admin_api_url(request):
    request.GET._mutable = True
    client_id = request.GET.pop('client_id', None)
    request.GET._mutable = False
    return client_id[0] if client_id else None
```

So that your query parameter is uknown to django admin site(removed before request reaches admin views). Please note, that this middleware should be on top of middleware list in settings.

This is dirty, and hacky. Though i didn't find better solution yet.